# Using of <contentFiles> in dotnet core

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

I got a website in net core 2. this website reference a custom nuget package
I would like deploy json files embedded in my nuget package in website on

```
dotnet restore
```

I tried to use a .nuspec file

```
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>HELPPLZHELP</id>
        <version>1.0.41</version>
        <authors>AAAAAA</authors>
        <owners>AAAAA</owners>
        <description>test nuspec file</description>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <contentFiles>
             <files include="*.json" buildAction="Content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true" />
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
<files>
    <file src="*.json" target="contentFiles" />
</files>
```

but this is not working

I try to  follow this links without success
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1908
https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html

Can you tell me what i miss ?

Thanks for help

Comment: The contentfiles are static in NuGet.

The buildAction is done on "build". 

Can you please clarify "what's not working"?

Comment: The problem was taht the json files are not copy in my client folder.
I found my problem. This functionnality works with visual studio 2017 but not with vscode or other lightweight IDE.

Comment: That's likely a build target break.

The specific target that's supposed to be doing this copying is likely not executed. 

I'd suggested opening an issue to respective repositories if this doesn't work.